# keframe error: no suitable context info for active keying set

Tags: rigging, keyframes

I am trying to animate Minecraft with a rig, but every time I press <kbd>I</kbd>, or <kbd>G</kbd>, it comes up with the error message.

```
no suitable context info for active keying set
```

Why, and how do I fix this so I can animate?

Comment: Can you add more details? What are you trying to animate?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I figured I'd answer it anyways. I recently ran into this as well. The problem could be that you had **multiple layers selected when you created the keying set**, so when adding additional keyframes you have to have all of the same layers selected. At least, this was the case for me.

Comment: In my case, I had the same error and then I discovered that I had "Available" selected in the built in Keying Keying Set (Timeline pane, bottom right, next to the red button - for beginners). It's better to have it clean if you don't know what kind of animation you are doing yet or select the options from the drop down menu.